# PHP XMLReader::VALIDATE, always valid

Tags: php, xml, validation

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something but my example below always prints "The XML is valid" to the screen, how is this possible as the XML is clearly broken? I'm on PHP 5.5.6 by the way.

```
// index.php
<?php
/*
 * PHP XMLReader - Check if a xml document is valid
 */
$reader = new XMLReader();
//$reader->open('./valid.xml');
$reader->open('./invalid.xml');

// Set parser options - you must set this in order to use isValid method
$reader->setParserProperty(\XMLReader::VALIDATE, true);

if ($reader->isValid()) {
    echo "The XML is valid";
} else {
    echo "The XML is NOT valid";
}
```

And the XML

```
// invalid.xml
<?xmlthisisnotvalid version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
    <to unclosedattribute=">Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleXMLElement for me like this worked.

The assertTrue method is from phpunit.

```
    $xmlreader = new \SimpleXMLElement(
            $XMLstringTOValidate, 0, false,
            $urlForXSD
    );

    $this->assertTrue(is_object($xmlreader));
```

Documentation for the SimpleXMLElement constructor is at 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php

I had initially set out to use XMLReader, but I couldn't get it to fetch the .xsd.